# Storing functions in ArangoDB documents as plain text

Tags: javascript, arangodb

I would like to be able to store functions in ArangoDB documents. From what I have seen, this is actually possible, since user-defined AQL functions seem to be stored that way, as plain strings. My question goes in that direction: how are those strings converted to callable functions afterwards?

Right now I found a working solution which I don't really like (eval usage seems to be discouraged). I am looking for a better solution. I can store functions and use them afterwards in the following way:

```
var fnString = "['a','b', function(a,b) { return a + b }]";
var fn = Function.apply(null, eval(fnString));
var someValue = fn(1,2)     //returns 3
```

Is there out a better way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there's no another way to store code in storage engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point the function code must be converted from a string to something executable.
This can be achieved by (evil) eval, but its usage is discouraged as you say. Eval can execute arbitrary code, and normally that's not what one wants.

Another way is to use the Function constructor:

```
var fn = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
var someValue = fn(1, 2); // returns 3
```

Using the Function constructor limits the potential harm, because the code is not executed directly, but only when the function is called. When the function is called, the potential damage the code can cause is limited to the scope of the function itself.

So in summary using the Function constructors should be a lot better than using eval.
Still, JSLint will tell you that the Function constructor is eval. But if you need to create functions from strings dynamically, then there's nothing you can do about it except silencing it like this.

```
/*jslint evil: true */
var fn = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
/*jslint evil: false */
```